# How to configure cmake for msys2

Tags: cmake, msys2, cmake-gui

I'm using external cmake with msys2, since cmake-gui provided by msys2 won't run (invalid win32 application). Now the problem is there's only so much I can configure using cmake-gui. I downloaded `OpenALSoft` today and when I ran `make install` it installed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\`. How do I configure external cmake to install into `mingw32` or `mingw64` depending on what's running? On top of that, I'm having a problem differentiating between `PATH` `RPATH` and `PREFIX` (and how those correspond to msys2 install structure), so if you could, please, clarify those too, I'd really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

I always use this invocation to make sure the install directory is set to `/mingw32` or `/mingw64`:

```
MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=- cmake . -G"MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$MINGW_PREFIX
```

And then when you want to install the built project, you must do this:

```
make install DESTDIR=/
```

All of this trickiness is due to the fact that CMake is a native Windows program that does not understand MSYS2-style paths like `/`, and MSYS2 has some automatic conversions of paths that happen when it detects you are running a native Windows program like CMake.

By the way, MSYS2's `cmake-gui` works for me, so maybe you should try reinstalling the CMake package in MSYS2 or something.  However, I expect my answer to work for both the external CMake and the one in MSYS2.

Comment: That should be run for every project. I'm trying to do all CMake-related operations via the GUI (of the standalone version), like setting CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to C:/msys64/mingw64. But I wanna do all the changes only once, not for every project. I tried making a toolchain file, but there's not enough info about it. Also, after last update, msys2's cmake-gui complains about a qt5 dll, I have no intention to install 12GB of QT5 just for cmake-gui.

Comment: Thanks for the hints about "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX" and "make install DESTDIR=/"! I used this and native Msys2 cmake/make finally tried to install in /usr/local rather than /Program Files.... However, although Cmake/make says it installs in /usr/local/bin there is nothing there. Any clues?

Comment: Ignore my problem. It was caused by me setting CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX in the CMakeList.txt explicitly, which somehow interfered with this solution. Sorry.